# How to inherit views properly in openerp 7.0

Tags: openerp-7

hi my view inheritance code is this , i get the following error while using this code .  " ValueError: too many values to unpack "

Please help me to resolve this issue

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="inherit_form_view1">
        <field name="name">Inherit Form</field>
        <field name="model">student.info.student</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="student.info.student.form_view1" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <!-- <xpath expr="/sheet/notebook/page/field[@name='mname']" position="after">
                <field name="m_tongue" />
            </xpath -->>

            <field name="mname" positon="after">
            <field name="m_tongue" />
            </field>

        </field>
    </record>

</data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="inherit_form_view1">
    <field name="name">Inherit Form</field>
    <field name="model">student.info.student</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="student_info_student.form_view1" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <field name="mname" positon="after">
            <field name="m_tongue" />
        </field>

    </field>
</record>
```

Your **ref is wrong**! structure must be "module_name"."view_name". Further using xpath is usually safer and preferable but this way is, if you are a beginner, clearer.

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Thanks for replying me, i got it